# Cálculo de semelhança entre palavras com Java

Tags: java, string, algoritmo

Para duas *string* A e B, definimos que a semelhança destas *strings* é o comprimento do prefixo que é comum a ambas. Por exemplo, a semelhança das *strings* `abc` e `abd` é 2, enquanto a semelhança das *strings* `aaa` e `aaab` é 3.

Calcule a soma de semelhanças de uma *string* S com cada um dos seus sufixos, incluindo a própria *string* como o primeiro sufixo.

**Formato de Entrada:**

A primeira linha contém o número de casos de testes T. Cada uma das T linhas próximas contém uma *string* cada.

**Formato de Saída:**

Exiba T linhas de saída, cada uma contendo um número inteiro que é para o caso de teste correspondente.

**Premissas:**

- 1 <= T <= 10
- As *strings* contém apenas caracteres minúsculos [a-z]

**Exemplo de entrada:**

```
2
ababaa
aa
```

**Exemplo de saída:**

```
11
3
```

**Explicação:**

Para o primeiro caso, os sufixos da *string* são `ababaa`, `babaa`, `abaa`, `baa`, `aa` e `a`. As semelhanças de cada uma dessas *string* com a *string* `ababaa` são 6, 0, 3, 0, 1, 1 respectivamente. Assim a resposta é 6 + 0 + 3 + 0 + 1 + 1 = 11. Para o segundo caso a resposta é 2 + 1 = 3

**Dúvidas**

No resultado da comparação:

```
6 + 0 + 3 + 0 + 1 + 1 = 11
```

De onde sai o 0? Como é feita a comparação?

Por enquanto, tenho só a assinatura do método, que ficaria de esse jeito:

```
public static Integer semelhancaString(Integer n, String... strings) {}
```

Comment: Bom.O site é para correção de código e análise de código. Tenta criar um código que fazemos a análise dele.
Porém na comparação ocorre com a string "aa" ocorre um erro.

Pois o resulta deveria ser 1+0+1+0+2+1 = 5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui resolver, fazendo assim o código fica mais limpo:

```
public static void semelhancaString(Integer n, String... strings) {
List<String> listStrings;
String stringBase, stringComparator;
Integer quantidade = 0;

listStrings = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(strings));
stringBase = listStrings.get(0);

for (int j = 1; j < n; j++) {
    stringComparator = listStrings.get(j);
    quantidade = contaQuantidadeDeIgualdade(stringBase, stringComparator);
    System.out.println(
        "A suma das Semelhanças entre: " + stringBase + " e " + stringComparator + " é " + quantidade);
}
}

public static Integer contaQuantidadeDeIgualdade(String base, String comparator) {
Integer quantidade = 0;
for (int i = base.length(); i > 0; i--) {
    String substring = base.substring(0, i);
    if (comparator.contains(substring)) {
    quantidade++;
    }

}
return quantidade;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ao invés de passar um monte de `String`, fica mais fácil se você passar como parametro um `Array` ou `List` de `String`.

E como retorno não é possível criar um retorno que tenha *T Linhas* do tipo `Interger`, a única maneira é retorna um `Array` de `Integer` ou por `String`

Uma alternativa de criação é esta que montei abaixo

```
String[] s1 = {"ababaa", "babaa", "abaa", "baa", "aa", "a"};
String[] s2 = {"ababaa", "aa"};

private static String semelhancaString(int n, String[] s1, String[] s2) {
            StringBuilder saida = new StringBuilder();

            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                int total = 0;
                for (int j = 0; j < s1.length; j++) {
                    String palavra1 = s1[j];
                    String palavra2 = s2[i];

                    int index = 0;
                    int nComparações = 0;
                    while (index < palavra1.length() && index < palavra2.length()) {
                        if (palavra1.charAt(index) == palavra2.charAt(index)) {
                            index++;
                            nComparações++;
                        } else {
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    total += nComparações;
                }
                saida.append(total + "\n");

            }
            return saida.toString();
        }
```